# How do I show the PHP variable value in the JavaScript pop-up?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have the following scripts. The user will pass a numerical value e.g. 123 as a parameter in the URL, and the app will load/fetch that value from MySQL and show it in the textarea.

E.g., entering, "example.com/index.php?id=123" in the URL will pull the 123rd record from the database and show it in the textarea. Everything seems to be working, but I want to show the last row/id of the "source" table when the form is submitted. So, instead of showing "Saved!" in the pop-up, it should show something like "124" (or, the last updated row/number).

index.php:

```
<?php
include('connect-db.php');
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT content FROM source WHERE id=$id") or die(mysqli_error()); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

       if($row)
    {
     $submit_date = date("Ymd");
     $content = $row['content'];                    
    }

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>        

     <script type="text/javascript"> 
          $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#myform").submit( function () {    
                  $.post(
                   'submit.php',
                    $(this).serialize(),
                    // 
                   // show the last id here!
                   //
                        function(data){ alert("Saved!"); }
                  );
                  return false;   
                });   
            });
    </script>      

      </head>
      <body>

    <div id="header" >

    <form action="submit.php" method="post" id="myform">
    <textarea id="editor" name="editor" id="editor"><?php echo $content; ?></textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>

    </form>

    </div>

      </body>
    </html>
```

submit.php:

```
<?php
include('connect-db.php');

$submit_date = date("Ymd");
$content = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['editor']));
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if ($content != '') { 
// 
// Show the variable (last_id) value in the JavaScript above!
//
$last_id = mysql_insert_id();  

mysql_query("INSERT INTO source (submit_date, ip, content) values('$submit_date','$ip_address','$content')") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($connection);
}
?>
```

connect-db:

```
<?php
 $server = 'localhost';
 $user = 'domdom';
 $pass = 'password@123';
 $db = 'domdom';

 $connection = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass) or die ("Could not connect to server ... \n" . mysql_error ());
 mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Could not connect to database ... \n" . mysql_error ());
?>
```

Please note that I do not need any advice on PDO or MySQLi, that is not important at this time. However, any suggestions on improving the security/SQL query etc. are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you using prepared statements? They're almost identical to the syntax that you're used to.

Comment: Your last statement confuses me.  PDO/MySQLi == improvements in query security.

Comment: you are also vulnerable to HTML injection (XSS)

Comment: I will use mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars) to fix that...thanks for noticing.

Comment: @MumboJumbo, you really should use `htmlspecialchars()` when displaying the text, not when inserting it in the database. This way, the database won't contain HTML and you will be able to use the text in other contexts as well if you might need it. You should usually escape for the current destination (if inserting in the database, escape for the database, if inserting in HTML, escape for HTML, but not both at the same time).

Comment: @rid I actually want to save HTML in MySQL... would u still suggest not to use htmlspecialchars while inserting the data?

Comment: @MumboJumbo, if you're inserting HTML in the database, then yes, use `htmlspecialchars()` (because you're inserting text inside HTML, so you need to escape for HTML, then you're inserting the HTML in the database, so you need to escape for the database)

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer in 2 parts:

[1] PHP side: in the "isset($_GET['id'])" section, just return the content of the text area you want to fill out. Say, in your DB, 123 -> 'Friday'. Just return the String 'Friday'.

[2] Client side: Do not "submit" the form. Call a JS function, and in there, create an XmlHttpRequest, and send the request to the server as an AJAX request. When you get the return value, examine it and populate your HTML textarea.

If you think this method is suitable for you and you need more details, let me know. I do this in many of my sites.